# Typescript _co.Function is not a Function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Working on an Ionic project, I have a TS function that is supposed to reveal an HTML element, the problem is is that when it's clicked I get an error saying it's not a function.

Here is the Stack Error

```
TypeError: _co.UnfoldAchievement is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/TravelPage.ngfactory.js:67:35)
    at handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13963:155)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15472:42)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15059:12)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10378:25)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11003:38
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:39492:53)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
```

Here are my Ionic settings

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.0
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 8.11.3
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
```

And here is my code.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TravelPage } from '../travel/travel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TravelPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TravelPage),
  ],
})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-travel',
  templateUrl: 'travel.html'
})

export class TravelPageModule {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

    UnfoldAchievement()
    {
        let achievement = document.getElementById("World-Explorer-Content");

            achievement.style.display = "contents";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you having multiple typos in your project? Why do you have an exported class called TravelPageModule when you clearly have @Component on top? Also are you sure you are calling that function from inside `travel.html`? One last thing. Never use document.* functions. Use the renderer2 API or directives like ngStyle to change such things.

Comment: I had been experimenting with the code to see if I was missing something. So turns out what my original issue had been was that I was working in the .module.ts file rather than the .ts file. The function wasn't found because it was in the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out what my original issue had been was that I was working in the .module.ts file rather than the .ts file. The function wasn't found because it was in the wrong file.